# Microphone not working for Chromium,MS Teams,GMeet

Tags: 20.04, microphone, lts

I am using Lenovo Ideapad 330. I tried restarting pulseaudio, installed Vokoscreen. Wired headset microphone is not detected at all. Internal microphone is just giving static noise (When checked through Discord Chromium). Vokoscreen and Gnome-screen recorder is recording audio. But, when it comes to any other app it just reads static noises from microphone. I'm using plain Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. The problem started as soon as I updated my PC to 20.04 version, it was working fine for 18.04 Bionic Beaver.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please edit your question and mention whether you are using a variant like Kubuntu/Xubuntu, or plain Ubuntu. Also mention some of the settings you configured. Also, is this issue present since the installation of Ubuntu, or did it come up after any update?  Also, is this a laptop with an internal microphone (which model?) or a desktop with an external microphone? Does microphone work when you plug in an earphone? Providing these information may help us help you.